# update_checkout No funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Actualmente tengo un carrito en woocommerce que al actualizar una información lo fuerzo para que me haga la actualizacion automatica, sin embargo, con el siguiente codigo lo que hace es mostrar que esta cargando pero nunca actualiza
`jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');`

Por alguna razón no actualiza, hace como que estuviera cumpliendo la funcion pero más nada,
lo llamo de la siguiente manera: primero detecto si hubo un cambio

`document.getElementById("num_dias").addEventListener("change", click);`

Luego realizo la funcion

```
function click(){
  
      jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
    
}
```

A la funcion click le tengo otro metodo que probe y este si me funciona, pero tarda aproximadamente 3 segundos para actualizar

Esto hace que de un click al boton menos y asi el sistema realiza la actualizacion

`document.querySelector(".minus").click();`

Comment: ¿Que evento es "update_checkout"?  ¿puedes mostrar donde esta definido?

Comment: Según es una funcion de woocommerce